"Hands" or "arms" in Song of Songs 5:14?

Нis hаnds аrе rоds оf gоld sеt with bеrуl. Нis bоdу is саrvеd ivоrу inlаid with sаррhirеs (5:14)

The word יד used here means "hand". "Arm" is  another word זרוע. The word translated as "rods" is גליל. It means a cylinder. But hand doesn't look like a cylinder at all. "Arms" would be better to be described as "rods/cylinders". Can יד mean "arm"?

Hebrew term for "hand" may also mean "arm" - not every language makes such a sharp distinction of various parts of this extremity as English (and English speakers don't mind that an arm consists of several parts.)

There are two words for 'hand' in Hebrew. Yod (or Jod) is the working hand or fist. Kaph is the palm of the hand. The soft part, the skillful part. The sensitive part. And the part that can enclose something within itself (important in doctrine and in regard to 'atonement' and the lid of the ark kaporeth.) Kaph is also used for the sole of the feet. (important in regard to surefootedness - divding the hoof - and maintaining a straight path). So lots of spiritual allusion to think about, especially in regard to the Song of Songs which is Solomon's. Up-voted +1.

Song of Songs is exquisite Hebraic poetry, often lost on us modern English-speaking people. As the details of language have already been gone into by another, there remains another point in the Hebrew scriptures that might be helpful in opening up our minds as to whether 'hand' or 'arm' is meant.
Only this morning I was studying parts of the book of Isaiah, and noted these three related verses, that seemed to interweave hand and arm. The first example requires two different literal translations to be compared, to show how closely the words for hand and arm appear in Hebrew:

"Behold, the Lord God will come with strong [hand] and his arm shall
rule for him" Isaiah 40:10 KJV
"Lo, the Lord Jehovah with strength cometh, And his arm is ruling for
him" Ibid. YLT

Isn't that comparison interesting? Isn't it telling, as to the close connection between the Hebrew words for arm and hand? When you think about it, perhaps the only time in the entire Hebrew scriptures that the hand of God works powerfully without any apparent connection to the arm is the vision of his writing on the wall of Belshazzar's palace during his impious feast (Daniel 5:5-28). The fingers of a hand writing are specified, but no arm is indicated.
Now consider two other verses in Isaiah that make the inter-twining of hand and arm even clearer:

"I will strengthen thee; yea, I will help thee; yea, I will uphold
thee with the right hand of my righteousness." Isaiah 41:10 KJV
"Who hath believed our report? and to whom is the arm of the Lord
revealed?" Isaiah 53:1 KJV

Faith rests on the powerful arm of God's righteousness. God's arm and faith in God's report go together. And God's reports are written down by him, through writing, caused by the invisible hand of the Holy Spirit, which reports are then handed over to God's people for them to believe in, by faith.
This is the other point in the Hebrew scriptures that might be helpful in opening up to our minds the interconnectedness of the hand and the arm, in scripture.

There is also, of course, the tables of stone 'written with the finger of God'. And the writing on the ground, all round a woman being condemned . . . . . . So, three times (significantly). Up-voted +1.

The OP has directed a good question to the wrong word.
יָד=yad means hand (or numerous related ideas like power, or stylus). It's a basic word for an innate concept that has cognates in Arabic and Akkadian.
A straightforward example is:-
פֶּן־יִשְׁלַ֣ח יָדֹ֗ו וְלָקַח֙ = = "lest he put out his hand and take" (Genesis 3:22)
But as the OP rightly says, it's not obvious how a hand is like a rod.
Does גָּלִיל=galil mean a rod at all?
Most of the major translations have "rods". But KJV and YLT have "rings".
New KJV switches out "rings" for "rods" which is interesting (and probably means this is more complicated than it looks).
Strong's only has 2 other occurrences, and these seem to mix nounal and adjectival examples.

1Kings 6:34
וּשְׁתֵּ֥י דַלְתֹ֖ות עֲצֵ֣י בְרֹושִׁ֑ים שְׁנֵ֨י צְלָעִ֜ים הַדֶּ֤לֶת
הָֽאַחַת֙ גְּלִילִ֔ים וּשְׁנֵ֧י קְלָעִ֛ים הַדֶּ֥לֶת הַשֵּׁנִ֖ית
גְּלִילִֽים׃
and two doors of cypress wood. The two leaves of the one door were
folding, and the two leaves of the other door were folding.



Esther 1:6
ח֣וּר ׀ כַּרְפַּ֣ס וּתְכֵ֗לֶת אָחוּז֙ בְּחַבְלֵי־ב֣וּץ וְאַרְגָּמָ֔ן
עַל־גְּלִ֥ילֵי כֶ֖סֶף וְעַמּ֣וּדֵי שֵׁ֑שׁ מִטֹּ֣ות ׀ זָהָ֣ב
וָכֶ֗סֶף עַ֛ל רִֽצְפַ֥ת בַּהַט־וָשֵׁ֖שׁ וְדַ֥ר וְסֹחָֽרֶת׃
There were white cotton curtains and violet hangings fastened with
cords of fine linen and purple to silver rods and marble pillars,
and also couches of gold and silver on a mosaic pavement of porphyry,
marble, mother-of-pearl, and precious stones.


So I'm not seeing how we think we know what this word means. I'll look at the lexicon rather than Strong's.
https://archive.org/details/geseniusshebrewc0000gese/page/n189/mode/2up
גלגל is a wheel.
גלגלת is a skull.
https://archive.org/details/geseniusshebrewc0000gese/page/n191/mode/2up
גְּלִילִֽ is a turning or a ring or a region
So I'll buy that it's something round from the etymology with skull and wheel.
There might be some historic information somewhere about ancient door technology, but that's usually a duck-shoot.
And this could so easily be a lost derived usage about the "ring" the hands make when the thumb is clasped to the forefinger.
There isn't a verb to be - so this is a tight metaphor.

The LXX
I have left the LXX to one side because they apparently felt the need to paraphrase this as χεῖρες αὐτοῦ τορευταὶ χρυσαῖ πεπληρωμέναι θαρσείς = 'the hands of him - golden chisellers(???) - having been filled are bold'
τορευταὶ is a rare word for a worker who carves reliefs. The only examples in Liddell & Scott (1897) for τορευτής are Polybius, Dionysius of Halicarnassus, and an inscription (which I'd struggle to find).
The Polybius citation is broken (it says 16.10.3) and the word τορευτής is very similar to τοξότης=archer so might have disappeared in a feat of papyrology.
Dionysius of Halicarnassus' De Compositione Verborum has it twice at https://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A2008.01.0586%3Achapter%3D25

ἄλλως τε καὶ τῶν τότε ἀνθρώπων οὐ γραπτοῖς ἀλλὰ γλυπτοῖς καὶ τορευτοῖς ἐοικότας ἐκφερόντων λόγους, λέγω δὲ Ἰσοκράτους καὶ Πλάτωνος τῶν σοφιστῶν
the authors of that day were producing discourses which suggested not writing but carving and chasing—those, I mean, of the sophists Isocrates and Plato
ἢ ζῳγράφων τε καὶ τορευτῶν παισὶν ἐν ὕλῃ φθαρτῇ χειρῶν εὐστοχίας
the disciples of painters and workers in relief, who display the dexterity and industry of their hands in a perishable medium

So to conclude this detour, (i) we hardly know what the Greek word is (ii) it isn't a gloss for גָּלִיל=galil (iii) it doesn't mean anything like rod.
Which is ominous for our word study because it probably means the Hebrew metaphor was foreign to Greek-literate Jewish translators in the 2nd Century BC. So we stand little hope!

Rods doesn't work for me, and I wonder if it's an artefact of conceptual translation plus some tenuous archaeological link. As if to say "This sort of door would have been held up with... rods! Got it. Job jobbed."
Rings doesn't work very well either because it doesn't conjure up the mental image of a hand.
Turning to the commentaries, it looks like a typical mess with someone saying "what if it's cylinders" (quite logical since the circular ideas of skull or a wheel are the positive shape not its negative hole) and then the others start hedging their bets with "ring... or maybe cylinder".
And of course since it's the Song of Solomon, this might not be the ring of the thumb and fingers, or the cylinder of the forearm... but that slightly ring-like, slightly cylinder-ish shape that a man needs to put his hand into before he can put it into a... Shulamite.
Which puts the OP's "hands or arms" question in a different light!

+1 Nicely researched! Let’s also see how Jewish scholars interpreted the Hebrew in the third or second century BCE. The Greek Septuagint (ABP) reads, “His hands are as turned gold, being filled with Tharsis stone.”

@Dieter oh I was just doing so - hope the information I have added is of interest
